# Neatly organise single column csv/excel data into JSON arrays

Tags: arrays, json, excel

I have a single excel column that contains a date, then 48 entries (a time and a height) relating to that date, before repeating with the same thing for an entire year. Similar to this:

| dd/mm/yy |
| --- |
| hh:mm x.x m |
| hh:mm x.x m |
| ... continues |
| hh:mm x.x m |
| hh:mm x.x m |
| dd/mm/yy |
| hh:mm x.x m |
| hh:mm x.x m |
| ... continues |
| hh:mm x.x m |
| hh:mm x.x m |
| dd/mm/yy |
| hh:mm x.x m |
| hh:mm x.x m |
| ... continues |
| hh:mm x.x m |
| hh:mm x.x m |

Using text to columns I can readily separate my data into 3 columns, where all the cells below the date will be blank, like so:

| dd/mm/yy |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | hh:mm | x.x | m |
|  | hh:mm | x.x | m |
|  | ... continues | ... continues | m |
|  | hh:mm | x.x | m |
|  | hh:mm | x.x | m |
| dd/mm/yy |  |  |  |
|  | hh:mm | x.x | m |
|  | hh:mm | x.x | m |
|  | ... continues | ... continues | m |
|  | hh:mm | x.x | m |
|  | hh:mm | x.x | m |
| dd/mm/yy |  |  |  |
|  | hh:mm | x.x | m |
|  | hh:mm | x.x | m |
|  | ... continues | ... continues | m |
|  | hh:mm | x.x | m |
|  | hh:mm | x.x | m |

I need to turn this data into JSON arrays, so that I can represent the data using chart.js based on a selected date. the expected output format would be:

> "dd/mm/yy":["x.x", "x.x", "... continues", "x.x", "x.x"]

Where for each dd/mm/yy there are the 48 height values within the array. The times (hh:mm) are actually irrelevant as they are the same for all the entries.

I think I need an excel formula that finds a date in column a, then appends the following 48 cells in column c.

Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Comment: What you want isn't built it directly to Excel, you'd have to write some code in VBA to achieve exactly what you want (I think).  But try [this site](https://tableconvert.com/excel-to-json), it may help.

Comment: Thanks @PeterT. 

I think your site is really useful - although my problem perhaps remains, that I do still need to manipulate the excel data somehow to generate the correct json array. 

For example, if I type a formula in excel (where A1 is the port name for that year, and a2 is the FIRST of the 365 dates):

' ="{""port"":"""&A1&""",""date"":"""&A2&""",""heights:""["""&B3&"""," &"""" &B4&"""," &"""" &B5&"""," &"""" &B6&"""," &"""" &B7 &"""]}" '

I get a json array as the output. For brevity I've only included the first cell references, as it gets quite long.

Comment: The array it then outputs is correct, it looks like this:
'{"port":"Victoria","date":"01/01/2002","heights:"["5.3","5","4.5"]}'

For me to manually update all those cell references for each of the 365 days would take forever - so I think before I run the spreadsheet through the json website you linked, I need to find a way to get my spreadsheet format correct.